# Evaluating a variable whose name is stored in a string

Tags: emacs, elisp

Consider a problem of evaluating a variable who's name is a string:

```
(defun string-dereference ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((myStr "rst-adjust"))
  ;; (describe-function 'myStr) => Symbol's function definition is void: myStr
  ;; (funcall (format "(describe-function '%s)" myStr) => Invalid function: "(describe-function 'rst-adjust)")
  )
```

While the following works

```
(describe-function 'rst-adjust)
```

How do I do that given `rst-adjust` is stored in a string?

**Edit**:

The answer is:

```
(describe-function (intern myStr))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`intern` is the function you're looking for:

```
(let ((my-str "rst-adjust"))
  (intern my-str))
==> rst-adjust
```